How can I make that my app How can I make my React app able to download a PDF or view one when it's running on an iOS operating system or an iPhone?
I'm trying to download a PDF file by making a GET request to an API. Currently, it works for all platforms, but when I try it on an iPhone, I can't do it.
const downloadCertificate = async () => {
    const getUrl = `${urlBase}/pdf/v1/${certificate}`;

    axios({
      method: "get",
      url: getUrl,
      responseType: "blob",
      headers: { orgid: orgid, Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute("download", "certificado.pdf"); 
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();

        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        document.body.removeChild(link);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  };

I tried using this code, but it doesn't work as expected:
const downloadCertificate = async () => {
    const getUrl = `${urlBase}/pdf/v1/${certificate}`;

    axios({
      method: "get",
      url: getUrl,
      responseType: "blob",
      headers: { orgid: orgid, Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/i)) {
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onloadend = () => {
            const url = reader.result;
            window.open(url, "_blank");
          };
          reader.readAsDataURL(response.data);
        } else {
          const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
          const link = document.createElement("a");
          link.href = url;
          link.setAttribute("download", "certificado.pdf");
          document.body.appendChild(link);
          link.click();
          window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
          document.body.removeChild(link);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  };

